# command output only in logfile and not in command window of Windbg

Tags: windbg

How can I Save the contents of command window directly into the logfile without displaying those contents on the command window of the WinDbg?

Comment: I don't think you can disable the output to the command window, you can call `cls` to clear the current text or hit the 'x' to close it, alternatively you could just run the command line version of windbg, 'cdb', pass it a txt file with your commands and output to your logfile. Is there an issue with the output to the command window?

Comment: I can think of one occasion, like using the ta or pa command to write every instruction to the command window (until an interrupt, break, or termination). I found that writing the output to the UI slows down the execution of WinDbg significantly after the command window fills up. Using the command line version (cdb) and outputting > file.log is much faster. I can still see the commands I type, although not the regular command window output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't know about this already, you can use the -log{o|a} [windbg command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) option to specify what log file you wish to write to. If you don't want any output to the cmd window at all you can redirect the output to `/nul`. i.e.:
`echo you cannot see me > /nul`
This does the same thing as redirecting command output to `/dev/null` on a *nix OS. It will execute the command, but nothing will be written to stdout.